# Getting gradle exception after updating to com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-type

Yesterday, I updated my google services gradle plugin to this:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

After that, I am getting below error in my `devDebug` flavour build:

```
Error:org.gradle.api.GradleException: No matching client found for package name 'com.example.android.dev'
```

Here are the relevant part of my app level `build.gradle` file:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android'
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 47
        versionName "1.3.2"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "example-debug"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            resValue "string", "app_name", "example"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
    }
```

This error does not come in my `prodRelease` product flavour build. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Your debug build has different application ID than your production build. Add an Android app with that app ID in your Firebase console and get a new configuration JSON.

Comment: @EugenPechanec If I register with the debug build application ID, will it work across all build types and flavours?

Comment: google-services.json will contain all information from the console at the time of download, so yes.

Comment: @EugenPechanec just to clarify, right now my app was registered with package name `com.example.android` and my debug build has package name `com.example.android.dev`. So I should register my app in Firebase console with the debug build package name, right?

Answer (score 1):

In your debug build type you are using this package:

```
 debug {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
    }
```

This message

> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.android.dev'

means that your `google-services.json` **doesn't contain this package**.

Follow these steps:

- Go to Firebase console
- add another android app registering also this package
- Export again the `google-services.json`

Answer (score 0):

Re-register your key on console.developers

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: Amit Tiwari has clarified my post details a min ago.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the issue.

The trick is to add another app to the `Firebase` console with the debug package name and debug `SHA1` fingerprint.

Doing this essentially creates 2 apps but the `google-services.json` file downloaded from any app contains information about both apps.